# Matching column values across multiple rows

Tags: sql, join, count, match

I have a table similar to this and need to count the number of orders that were same day, future dated or not completed.  A700 is presubmit and A18 is submitted.  They are matched on the UniqueID.  I think I need to use a JOIN but am not sure how to go about this.  Any pointers are much appreciated while I soldier on trying to work it out.

```
AuditID  |  ActivityDateTime  |  ProductCode  |  UniqueID  |  DeliveryDate
A700            2020-01-01         111111       1234567890      NULL
A700            2020-01-01         111111       2222222222      NULL
A700            2020-01-01         222222       9999999999      NULL
A700            2020-01-01         333333       5555555555      NULL

A18     2020-01-01         112233       1234567890      2020-01-01
A18     2020-01-01         112233       2222222222      2020-01-03
A18     2020-01-01         333333       5555555555      2020-01-03
```

Results:

```
ProductCode  |  SameDay  |  FutureDay
112233             1            1
333333             0            1
222222             0            0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like a self-join with aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select t700.productcode,
       sum(case when t700.ActivityDateTime = t18.DeliveryDate then 1 else 0 end) as sameday,
       sum(case when t700.ActivityDateTime < t18.DeliveryDate then 1 else 0 end) as futureday,
from t t700 join
     t t18
     on t700.uniqueid = t18.uniqueid and
        t700.auditid = 'A700' and
        t18.auditid = 'A18'
group by t700.productcode;
```

The `ActivityDateTime` column would seem to have a time component.  If so, you might need to adjust the comparisons for the same and future dates.

Comment: Sorry Gordon - got moved to something else and only just come back to this.  That helped massively and solved my issue. Thanks very much. :)